# Magento 2 - Can't print off pdf of invoice

Tags: magento-2.1

Under **sales > Invoices** I'm clicking the "**Print**" button to get a pdf of a invoice (see link) but it no longer works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OLfQ.png

**ERROR:**
There has been an error processing your request

> Warning: strspn() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/dragoni5/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/StringParser.php on line 162

Cheers.
Mike.

Comment: I'd really appreciate any feedback

Comment: Did you solve this yet? Please share your findings for this problem. Thank you.